# How to know child added to StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the efficient way to detect when child added to `StackPanel`? I am using `StackPanel` as example, it could be `Grid`, `WrapPanel` or any control that derives from Panel.

I am trying to add controls in two ways. Using XAML and PropertyChanged of AttachedProperty.

Here is some code:

```
public class Region : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegionNameProperty;
    static Region()
    {
        RegionNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RegionName",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Region),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback((s,e)=>
        {
            if(s is StackPanel)
            {
                 StackPanel stack = (StackPanel)s;
                 stack.Children.Add(new Button(){Content="Test2"});
            }
        }))
      );
   }
}
```

XAML:

```
        <StackPanel Name="stack2" local:Region.RegionName="MyRegion1">
            <Button Content="Test 1"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Here you can see that button "Test 2" added before button "Test 1".

Thanks,

Comment: What do you want that for??

Comment: @HighCore I am adding some controls on Setter of the attached property. I think Setter of the attached property is fired before the controls added on XAML. I need to know when controls added by XAML and reorder them.

Comment: I've modified my answer, check it out.

Comment: Setter of which attached property? You haven't shown anything like that in your question. Please provide more info about what exactly you are doing. And be aware of the fact that the setter of an attached property (or dependency property) is *not* invoked when that property is set in XAML.

Comment: @Clemens you are right. Setter of the attached property is not fired unless you add something from codebehind. I am adding controls to the stackpanel from AttachedProperty changed handler.

Comment: What about my solution? Does it work or not?

Comment: @WojciechKulik I realized that LayoutUpdated event is fired some other times even if I move the mouse.

Comment: and what about `StackPanel.UpdateLayout()`?

Comment: @WojciechKulik Do you think I can fire UpdateLayout() from XAML?

Comment: Wait... so where do you reorder your children collection? I thought that you do that in cs, so before that you could invoke UpdateLayout

Comment: @WojciechKulik See my update: button "Test 2" added before button "Test 1". I need some kind of trigger when button "Test 1" added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am adding two buttons to stackpanel.
>   1) from attached property changed - button "Test 2"
>   2) from XAML - button "Test 1".
>   The problem: button "Test 2" is added before "Test 1".

All controls are creating in "InitializeComponent" method in constructor (I assume), so you could do reordering in Window.Loaded event.
The xaml's button is creating only once, so one additional reorder in Loaded event should help.

**Old answer:**

There is an event `LayoutUpdated`, you could try this, more information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated.aspx

> I am adding some controls on Setter of the attached property. I think Setter of the attached property is fired before the controls added on XAML. I need to know when controls added by XAML and reorder them

Maybe after adding children, you should just call `StackPanel.UpdateLayout()` and then reorder